# sudo apt-get install ros-<hydro>-ros-tutorials not installing

Tags: ros, tutorial, ros-hydro, bash, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In tutorial 5: understanding ROS nodes, the lightweight simulator does not install. The message provided is...
bash: hydro: No such file or directory. Any idea how to get it working?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190242/sudo-apt-get-install-ros-%3Chydro%3E-ros-tutorials-not-installing/) by [Leevini](https://answers.ros.org/users/20016/leevini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-14

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-08-14**:
Please provide more information. Incluidng all the commands to reproduce your error. as well as the full error in the console. Just copy and paste the whole sequence from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you used the exact command above the problem is with the brackets. Try:

```
   sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-tutorials
```

Otherwise you will have to paste more info.

---

Originally posted by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) with karma: 150 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2